# How to change maxVisibleItems in QFileDialog filter combobox

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I have `QFileDialog` with 11 items in the filter. By default `QComboBox` shows 10 and for the rest you need to scroll - i.e. you have to scroll for 1 item. I would like to change it. `QComboBox` has `maxVisibleItems` property, but how can I access `QFileDialog`'s filter combobox? I can see it in `QDialogPrivate::qFileDialogUi->fileTypeCombo`, but I don't have access to it.

Thanks!

Comment: It is only theoretically possible with *non-native* dialogs. You would have to first create the dialog, and then use `findChildren` to locate the QComboBox. For native dialogs, its not possible via Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution **only** works for **non native** file dialogs (i.e. you must set the `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` flag).

In that case, [`QObject::findChild`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) can be used to find the combobox in the widget. The following example assumes the dialog has *only one combobox*. If thats not the case, you must find the correct one via `QObject::findChilden`, which returns a list of all children.

Example code could look like this:

```
auto dialog = new QFileDialog(parent);
dialog->setOptions(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
auto cBox = dialog->findChild<QComboBox*>();
if(cBox)
    cBox->setMaxVisibleItems(11);
else
    qCritical() << "Unable to find any combobox child";

//setup and show
```

**Important:** If you can't find the child, it's possible you have to first show the dialog before you can modify the box. In that case, place the code after the show call, and it might work.